# How do I write a grammar for a select sql statement?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, yacc

I am writing a grammar for an SQL parser and I've been stuck on this for a while now-

```
F:      FETCH  fields  FROM  tables  Conditions
;

fields:     ALL
|           ids
;

ids:        ID ids_
;

ids_:       ',' ID ids_
|            { /*empty*/ }
;

tables:     ID
;

Conditions:     WHERE  ConditionList 
|               { /*empty*/ }
;

ConditionList:      Condition ConditionList_
;

ConditionList_:     BoolOp Condition ConditionList_
|                   { /*empty*/ }
;

Condition:      Operand RELOP Operand
|               NOT Operand RELOP Operand
;

Operand:    ID
|           NUM
;

BoolOp:     AND
|           OR
;
```

For some reason when the lexer reads a FROM token, the parser terminates with an error. Here's the lex code-

```
FETCH{ printf("fetch ");            return FETCH;}
FROM        { printf("from ");  return UNIQUE;                                      }

ALL     { printf("all ");   return ALL;     }
WHERE       { printf("where ");     return WHERE;   }
AND         { printf("and ");   return AND;     }
OR      { printf("or ");    return OR;  }
NOT             { printf("not ");   return NOT; }
RelOp           { printf("%s", yytext);     yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return RELOP;   }
[0-9]*          {printf("num ");    return NUM; }
[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*      { printf("id ");        return ID;      }
{symbol}    { printf("%c ", yytext[0]); return yytext[0];       }
.                           {   }
```

RelOp is a pattern- `RelOp          ("<"|"<="|">"|">="|"=")`
and symbol is a pattern- `symbol            ("("|")"|",")`

Comment: What's the error message? Also please post a [MCVE] including the definitions of your lexer rules, the input on which the error occurs and the code or command line you're using to apply your grammar to the input.

Comment: the parser just calls yyerror and stops parsing. An example would be a typical SQL select statement except with FETCH instead of SELECT like-  `FETCH id1,id2 FROM table WHERE id3 = 341`

Comment: @YashSonawane: Please *edit your question* with the information requested, including the precise input which triggered the problem and as much detail about where the problem occurred as you have been able to ascertain.

Comment: Comment without looking too closely at the grammar: There is no point attempting to eliminate left-recursion from a grammar used in yacc/bison. Yacc/bison *prefer* left-recursion; trying to eliminate it needlessly complicates your grammar, also making it harder to read, and makes inefficient use of the parser stack. Write `ids` as `ids: ID | ids ',' ID`. Simpler, more readable, and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your grammar starts with

```
F:      FETCH  fields  FROM  tables  Conditions
```

However, your lexer rules includes

```
FROM        { printf("from ");  return UNIQUE; }
```

Since `UNIQUE` is different from `FROM`, the grammar rule won't apply.

If those `printf` calls in your lexer are some kind of debugging attempt, they are not very useful since they won't tell you whether you are actually returning the correct token type (and value, in the cases where that is necessary). I strongly recommend using [bison's trace feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing) to get an accurate view of what is going on. (Bison's trace will tell you which token type is being received by the parser, for example.)